# Which GPU runs my game and how to switch it

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, gpu, gaming

I know this has been asked already in one or another way but somehow reading all the posts did not quite help me.

So, I have got a Laptop with two GPUs (Intel HD Graphics 4000 and AMD Radeon HD 7970M) and I know that my Radeon GPU should work for the games I play. Recently bought Warhammer: End Times - Vermintide and it stutters like hell while playing on the lowest settings. When I look into the options of the game it only shows the Intel graphics. Although I set the vermintide.exe in CCC to max performance which should result in switching the graphic card for the game.

Is there a method to show which graphiccard currently runs or to document it in some kind of logfile?

Or: Would the PC automatically switch to the other GPU if i deactivated the Intel 4k in windows device manager?

Btw:

CPU: Intel Core i7 - 3630QM

OS: Win 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had CCC 13.1 installed and at this point there was no monitoring option for which app runs at which performance.

So I uninstalled it and downloaded the most recent version of the CCC (15.1). It now has an option that shows each running app and if it runs at hihg or low performance. That helped me big time and showed me which .exe I had to add to the switchable grphic application settings.

Answer (score 0):

Run the AMD Catalyst Center, go to the `switchable Graphic Application settings`, click on `Add application` and select the exe of the game and set it to high performance.

Now download the tool call [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) and add the AMD Radeon HD 7970M settings to the Gadget. If the GPU is not used you see this with `-` in the gadget:

[image]

If the GPU is used you see the GPU/Memory Speed, Temperature and the GPU usage:

[image]